# Gulp js minify bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, gulp

I have a workflow around gulp.

I would like to concat and minify my js files but I don't know how to do with the bootstrap's js folder (who contain affix.js, alert.js, etc...). I must concat this files with bootstrap.js ?

Here my website structure :

```
css/
    bootstrap.min.css
    main.min.css
scss/
    bootstrap.scss
    main.scss
img/
fonts/
js/
    bootstrap.js
    jquery.js
    modernizr.js
    bootstrap/
         affix.js
         alert.js
         button.js
         etc....
index.html
```

Comment: `bootstrap.js` should contain code for all plugins, if you didn't exclude any here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ . So you should be able to include only that file into your bundle.

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev So bootstrap.js and bootstrap folder contain the same plugin ?

Comment: Bootstrap folder contains code for individual files, see @tmarwen's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap jQuery Plugins can be included individually (each in a its own **.js* file as it seems you did), or all at once (will be all bundled in the *bootstrap.js* file).

As you are using a Gulp workflow, you can easily customize your input pipeline to include the plugins you may need in your applications, this should be the decision of yours as no one here can decide what of those plugins you may need.

So to put it in simple words, check what custom Javascript files your may need, and include them in your workflow steps (concatenation, minification...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So i will delete bootstrap JS files and include the plugins that I need. How to make a gulpfile task who allow to choice the plugins ? I must use a comment system to deactivate plugins that I didn't need ? There's no possibility to create a file where I can include the plugin's name like in a scss file ?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a capability, but defining your plugin names just as string literal could be fine. Isn't it?